# Single artificial neuron easily extendable to neural network

Tags: neural-networks, perceptron

I'm working on implementation of artificial neuron which be extended to neural net. I want do implementation by myself to fully understand how it works. I start with perceptron with threshold activation function:

[image]

and then questions come along

- can implementaion be change to operate with more than 2 classes?
- if I build network with few layers, first (and nexts) layers should return predicted class or value from first layer?
- Is better artificial neuron to build neural net than perceptron?

Answer (score 0):

- The implementation can be changed for more than two classes. You can either use two neurons or you can use the following structure:
  $$
  f(x)=\left\{\array{2 & \textrm{if} \;wx+b>0\\
  1 & \textrm{if} \; wx+b\leq 0 \; \textrm{and}\;ux+c>0\\
  0 & \textrm{otherwise} \\
  }\right.
  $$ where $u$ is of the same size as $w$ and $c$ is a scalar.
- Typically, only the output layers are used.
- The described neuron is better in terms of interpretation but is difficult to be trained by gradient-based algorithms such as backpropagation.